# Fedora 28 running Apache server and Laravel app

Tags: fedora, apache-httpd

Running Fedora 28 with Apache server and in `/var/www/html` having Laravel app. 
Apache is running under user `apache`. I'm starting the app with my current user, but getting Access denied for the `laravel.log` file in the app. Tried many different solutions on the web, changing mode to 777, changing owner, group, but none of them actually worked. There was a comment, stating that this is the default installation in Fedora for the test page and I have to create different virtual directory for my app with different user attached to the apache group. What is the right and working way of doing that?

Comment: How are you starting the app? Are you using `php artisan serve` as a user directly from the `/var/www/html` directory? Or are you using the default `index.php` via Apache?

Comment: Starting via `php artisan serve` as a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment, starting a Laravel App directly with `php artisan serve` with a *non privileged user* from a system directory (as `/var/www/html` is) creates a lot of permission problems.

Looks like you already have Apache installed, and deployed your application to the default web root.

The easiest step should be to make sure you have `mod_php` installed on your system,
checking if Apache configuration has the correct `DirectoryIndex` (something like
`DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.php`) and then just point your browser
to your server IP/name without using `php artisan serve` (let Apache do its thing ;) ).

If you instead would like to continue using `php artisan serve`, as an alternative, you can deploy the application to a subdirectory of your **home directory** (for example, `/home/youruser/my_app`), then you can use `php artisan serve` and have the correct permissions (as your user **owns** all the directories and files under your home).

Obviously, in this case you cannot use a *privileged port* like `80` or `443` as in the previous case (IIRC `php artisan serve` uses port `8000` by default).

So, using Apache+PHP you can reach your app via `http://my_app/`, while with the "artisan" method you'll reach it with something like `http://my_app:8000/`.

Comment: I went with `php artisan serve` and working like charm. Thank you.